# How to use gradle repositories based on if else?

Tags: android, gradle

I am android developer. I need to use different repositories based on office  or home like as below. But gradle failed to parse it correctly, it always use first maven repository. Would you like to let me know how to fix it to meet my requirement? Thank you very much.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    if(isInOffice){
        maven{
            url 'http://172.22.7.153:8081/repository/new_hunan/'
        }
    }else{
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you 100% sure your condition is correct (i.e. that `isInOffice` isn't always true)?

Comment: isInOffice is a variable in global gradle.properties. I had tried this, it is always use first one.

Comment: Finally, the root cause is that isInOffice=true in gradle.properties is String instead of Boolean, we need to parse to boolean by isInOffice.toBoolean(). Thanks.